# Flutter app not able to run in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

I have installed flutter and dart plugin in IntelliJ as suggested at flutter.io official doc but I am getting the below error.

```
Could not find an option named "machine".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure the Flutter plugin so that the SDK points to the Flutter install directory?

Comment: Yes I have done that.

Comment: What do you get when you run `flutter doctor` from command line?

Comment: [✓] Flutter (on Mac OS, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at <path>/flutter
    • Framework revision 9a0a0d9903 (5 months ago), engine revision f8d80c4617

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 24.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/globallogic/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-24, build-tools 24.0.1
    • Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)

[✓] Atom - a lightweight development environment for Flutter
    • flutter plugin version 0.2.6
    • dartlang plugin version 0.6.42

Comment: I think you should update Flutter. I get `• Framework revision d05c7f62f2 (vor 3 Wochen), 2016-12-21 06:19:42
`

Comment: What IntelJ version are you using? Stable or EAP?

Comment: Using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2
Build #IC-163.10154.41, built on December 21, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: The IDEA version should work. EAP is currently not supported.

Comment: Soo this intelliJ version should work right?

Comment: It worked I have updated the flutter version..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should update Flutter. When I run `flutter doctor` I get

```
• Framework revision d05c7f62f2 (vor 3 Wochen), 2016-12-21 06:19:42
```